# natvis - Add tabulator to output

Tags: visual-studio-2015, natvis

Is there a way to format the final output value string of the watch window with tabulators or other usually escaped symbols?

I have tried:

```
<Type Name="MyVector">
    <DisplayString Optional="true">x={myVal.x}, y={myVal.y}, z={myVal.z}</DisplayString>
</Type>
```

This results is:

[image]

I would like to have:

[image]

I have tried so far:

```
 {\t}
 \t
 {{\t}}
```

Sometimes things are quite hidden in the [MSDN Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [MSDN Code Blog](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Writing-type-visualizers-2eae77a2). But in this instance, I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've wanted to be able to do this for years, but no, I do not believe you can. Given that the font used in the autos/locals/watch windows are not fixed-width (and can not be changed, as far as I can tell), you'd still have trouble trying to line stuff up, even if you could add tabs.

Comment: Yeah, at the moment there is no option to do this. I'll leave this thread open in case in future releases it might be possible :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try typing &#009; for tabs, like

```
    <Type Name="MyVector">
        <DisplayString Optional="true">x={myVal.x},&#009;y={myVal.y},&#009;z={myVal.z}\</DisplayString>
    </Type>
```